# Calculate Time column from Date and Duration data - SQL Server ASP Classic

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have been trying to find a similar case, but couldn't find one that meet my case.

I have 2 tables in TestDB: Activity table with StartDate column, and a child table ActivityLog table with Duration column data.

```
Create Table Activity (
ActivityID int Not Null,
StartDate Date,
Summary varchar(255),
Primary Key (ActivityID)
);
```

And

```
Create Table ActivityLog (
ActivityID int Foreign Key References Activity(ActivityID),
LogID int Not Null Primary Key,
Duration int Not Null,
Comment varchar(255) Not Null
);
```

I write ASP Classic to generate a Table. My code is below:

```
<%
        'Set Variable
        Dim objCN 'ADO Connection Object
        Dim objRS 'ADO Recordset Object

        'Create a Connection Object
        Set objCN = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

        'Connect to SQL Server Database, connection string in Global.asa file                      
        objCN.Open Application("ConnStrTestDB")

        'SQL Query for select Person Name
         strSQLAct="SELECT a.StartDate, al.Duration, al.Comment FROM Activity AS a INNER JOIN ActivityLog AS al ON a.ActivityID = al.ActivityID"

         'Create Recordset
         Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
         objRS.Open strSQLAct, objCN
    %>

    <table>
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>Duration (hours)</th>            
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% Do While Not objRS.EOF %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%Response.Write(objRS("StartDate"))%></td>                                
                    <td><%Response.Write(objRS("Duration"))%></td>                                        
                    <td><%Response.Write(objRS("StartDate"))%></td>
                    <td><%Response.Write(objRS("Comment"))%></td>
                  </tr>
             <%
                objRS.MoveNext
                Loop
             %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--Close Recordset-->
    <%
        objRS.Close
        Set objRS = Nothing
    %>
```

I want to add Start Time and End Time column in the Result Table. Start Time is calculated from a.StartDate data, using Time value. End Time is Start Time + Duration. Duration is in Hours unit.

I really appreciate for any idea how I can achieve it.

Thanks

I follow @Aleksei Lychev answer, I tested the query in SQL Management Studio, it run give the result perfectly. And then I updated my ASP Classic as below:

```
<%
        'Set Variable
        Dim objCN 'ADO Connection Object
        Dim objRS 'ADO Recordset Object

        'Create a Connection Object
        Set objCN = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

        'Connect to SQL Server Database, connection string in Global.asa file                      
        objCN.Open Application("ConnStrTestDB")

        'SQL Query for select Person Name
         strSQLAct = "SELECT a.StartDate, a.Summary, al.Duration, al.Comment " + _
                     "DATEADD(hh, (SUM(al.Duration) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ActivityID ORDER BY al.LogID RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) - SUM(al.Duration) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ActivityID ORDER BY al.LogID RANGE CURRENT ROW)), CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, a.StartDate)) AS StartTime " + _
                     "DATEADD(hh, SUM(al.Duration) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ActivityID ORDER BY al.LogID RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING), CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, a.StartDate)) AS EndTime " + _
                     "FROM Activity AS a " + _
                     "INNER JOIN ActivityLog AS al ON al.ActivityID = a.ActivityID " + _
                     "ORDER BY a.ActivityID, al.LogID;"

         'Create Recordset
         Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
         objRS.Open strSQLAct, objCN
    %>

    <table>
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>Duration (hours)</th>            
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% Do While Not objRS.EOF %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%Response.Write(objRS("StartTime"))%></td>                                
                    <td><%Response.Write(objRS("EndTime"))%></td>                                        
                    <td><%Response.Write(objRS("Duration"))%></td>
                    <td><%Response.Write(objRS("Comment"))%></td>
                  </tr>
             <%
                objRS.MoveNext
                Loop
             %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--Close Recordset-->
    <%
        objRS.Close
        Set objRS = Nothing
    %>
```

The following error come up:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'hh'.
 /TestDBTimeLog.asp, line 30
```

I have tried Google it, but I can't find what cause the issue yet.

Comment: The issue will be support for the [`OVER` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) which was introduced in SQL Server 2008 and I doubt it is supported by the SQL Server ODBC Provider. You should consider [using the SQL Server Native Client](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-native-client-use/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the top of my head, assuming ActivityLogs within one Activity are ordered by LogID and also "sql-server" tag is right:

```
SELECT
    a.StartDate,
    a.Summary,
    al.Duration,
    al.Comment,
    DATEADD(hh,
        SUM(al.Duration) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ActivityID ORDER BY al.LogID RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) - SUM(al.Duration) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ActivityID ORDER BY al.LogID RANGE CURRENT ROW),
        CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, a.StartDate)) AS StartTime,
    DATEADD(hh,
        SUM(al.Duration) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ActivityID ORDER BY al.LogID RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),
        CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, a.StartDate)) AS EndTime
FROM Activity AS a
INNER JOIN ActivityLog AS al
    ON al.ActivityID = a.ActivityID
ORDER BY a.ActivityID, al.LogID
```

I'm not too good with window functions, and this definitely might be done better, but I hope you've got an idea.

Comment: Thanks very much @Aleksei Lychev. It works perfectly on SQL Management Studio, but when I try in ASP Classic, I got an error: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'hh'.  /TestDBTimeLog.asp, line 30". I will post the Answer, so you can see my ASP Code.

Comment: sorry I can't post my updated ASP code on the anwser cause it against the rules. I will try to edit my question.

Comment: I guess that's something to do with ODBC specific SQL parsing.
Could you please try replacing "DATEADD(hh" to "DATEADD(hour"?

Comment: it doesn't work. The same error come up: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'hour'.

Comment: Then it should really be an issue with ODBC Driver not being able to proceed OVER clause. Please refer the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49211049/calculate-time-column-from-date-and-duration-data-sql-server-asp-classic/49213522?noredirect=1#comment85440993_49211049) by @Lankymart